# Get all public facebook events in a given area?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql, facebook-events

Is there a way to get all public facebook events in a given area, regardless of wether you are linked to them in any way? I have seen a few posts on how to get events you are invited to but not to get all in an area?

Answer (score 1):

**Get All FaceBook Public Event :-**

```
SELECT name, pic_cover,start_time, end_time, location, description,venue  FROM event WHERE eid  in(SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid IN (SELECT page_id FROM place WHERE distance(latitude, longitude, "37.76", "-122.427") < 1000)) ORDER BY start_time desc limit 5
```

Thanks
JAY

Comment: What database are you referring to?

Comment: Is not possible to do it like that since FQL is deprecated after the Facebook API version 2.1

Comment: Correction: You can still use FQL until August 7th 2016 [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog)

Comment: and how to get the same results with FB graph API?